# Can not mount copy of image file (ddrescue): "can't have a partition outside the disk"

Tags: dd, disk-image, disk-cloning, ddrescue, parted

I'm struggling for days now moving my old `Windows XP` installation to a new hard disk, because the old disk is failing.

### Long story short:

I successfully created an image of the entire (failing) disk and was able to mount it in Linux.
I now want to copy it (the image file) to another disk, but the copy seems to have an error (see below)

### What I did

(among many other things)

I found this excellent tutorial: https://www.technibble.com/forums/threads/guide-to-using-ddrescue.48269/

#### cloning failing drive to .img with `ddrescue -d`

- installed `Linux Mint 17` on another drive in the PC
- bought a new 3 TB hard disk
- cloned the entire failing disk (Seagate, 500 GB) with `ddrescue` to an image file on a partition of the 3 TB hard disk
  `sudo ddrescue -d /dev/sdc Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.logfile`

Result:

> GNU ddrescue 1.17 Press Ctrl-C to interrupt rescued:   500107 MB, 
>   errsize:     512 B,  current rate:     1536 B/s    ipos:   392967 MB, 
>   errors:       1,    average rate:   27113 kB/s    opos:   392967 MB,
>   time since last successful read:       0 s Finished
>
> Logfile:
>   Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.17
>   Command line: ddrescue -d /dev/sdc Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.logfile
>   current_pos  current_status 0x5B7EA9B400     +
>        pos        size  status 0x00000000  0x5B7EA9B000  + 0x5B7EA9B000  0x00000200  - 0x5B7EA9B200  0x18F216AE00  +

#### tested the image and was able to mount it in Linux

> Sudo parted Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img  [sudo] password for martin: 
>   GNU Parted 2.3 Using /media/martin/data1/Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img
>   Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
>   (parted) unit
>   Unit?  [compact]? B
>   (parted) print
>   Model:  (file) Disk /media/martin/data1/Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img:
>   500107862016B Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition
>   Table: msdos
>
> Number  Start         End            Size           Type      File
>   system  Flags  1      32256B        70597578239B   70597545984B
>   primary   ntfs         boot  2      70605802496B  500105249279B 
>   429499446784B  extended               lba  5      70605834752B 
>   500105249279B  429499414528B  logical   ntfs
>
> (parted)
>
> sudo mkdir mountpoint
>
> sudo mount -o loop,ro,offset=70605834752 Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img
>   mountpoint

#### Copied the .img file to another disk (hfs+ volume)

In the Linux file explorer (Nautilus?) I copied the .img file to another disk. Unfortunately I only had enough space on a disk formatted `hfs+ (journaled)`, so I had to mount it with write permissions in Linux (like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os) ) and copied the .img file to it.

#### now parted can not list the partitions of the copied image:

still on the Linux machine with the hfs+ drive mounted after copying:

> martin@pcmint /media/martin/MacBak04 $ sudo parted
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img [sudo] password for martin:  GNU Parted 2.3
>   Using /media/martin/MacBak04/Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img Welcome to GNU
>   Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands. (parted) unit
>   Unit?  [compact]? B
>   (parted) print
>   **Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!**
>   (parted) quit

#### with sfdisk I can list the partitions:

> sudo sfdisk -d Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img  Warning: extended partition
>   does not start at a cylinder boundary. DOS and Linux will interpret
>   the contents differently. read: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> sfdisk: read error on Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img - cannot read sector
>   137901958
>    partition table of Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img unit: sectors
>
> Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img1 : start=       63, size=137885832, Id= 7,
>   bootable Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img2 : start=137901958,
>   size=838866107, Id= f Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img3 : start=        0,
>   size=        0, Id= 0 Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img4 : start=        0,
>   size=        0, Id= 0
>
> martin@pcmint /media/martin/MacBak04 $ sudo sfdisk -l
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img  Disk Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img: cannot
>   get geometry
>
> Disk Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img: 187 cylinders, 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder
>   boundary. DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently. read:
>   Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> sfdisk: read error on Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img - cannot read sector
>   137901958 Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes,
>   counting from 0
>
> Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img1   *      0+   8582    8583-  68942916    7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img2       8583+  60800   52218- 419433053+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img3   0       -       0          0    0  Empty 
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img4   0       -       0          0    0  Empty

#### the original image shows one more partition!

> martin@pcmint /media/martin/data1 $ sudo sfdisk -l
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img  [sudo] password for martin:  Disk
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img: cannot get geometry
>
> Disk Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img: 60801 cylinders, 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder
>   boundary. DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently. Units
>   = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0
>
> Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img1   *      0+   8582    8583-  68942916    7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img2       8583+  60800   52218- 419433053+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA) 
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img3       0       -       0          0    0  Empty 
>   Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img4       0       -       0          0    0  Empty Seagate500GB_ddrescue3.img5      8584+  60800   52217- 419433022    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

### Question

What have I done wrong? Is the copied image file damaged?

Can I fix it or do I have to chose another method to copy it somewhere else (maybe with `dd`=?

Comment: wow, nobody answered this yet?  im having same problem.  This is one hard error to research so im not going to try much further just yet.  I basically some dd images that i totally cant mount using the offsets.  I have  several images, they cant all be corrupt(prob are)...

Comment: @BrianThomas: I will have a look in my documentation later if I could solve it